# Rscript and Backticks

Tags: r, bash, shell, knitr, rscript

I need to run `knit2html` on the command line using `Rscript`. I tried the following code and it works

```
Rscript -e "(knitr::knit2html(text = '## good', fragment.only = TRUE))"
```

However, when I introduce R code chunks (or anything involving backticks), the process hangs. So the following does NOT work

```
Rscript -e "(knitr::knit2html(text = '## good\n `r 1 + 1`',fragment.only = T))"
```

For the purpose of my use, I only have access to the contents and hence can NOT pass a file to `knit2html`, which I know will work.

My question is how do I make this work. I know the problem is the backticks and I have tried looking at escaping them, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: It works for me. maybe an OS isssue.

Comment: I am on Mac OS 10.8.2. What OS are you on?

Comment: Have you tried using a "here file" or "here document" construct (with `Rscript <<EOF` on the first line, `EOF` on the last, and the contents of the "file" in between)? I've got no access to a *NIX box right now, but would be curious to know if that works...

Answer (score 0):

it is a shell issue.

On windows it works.

On linux You need to escape the backtick like \'

I think the reason , some shell interprets the double-quoted string once.

Comment: @Ramnath I test it in windows and Ubuntu. Tell me if this works for Mac OS.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on what might be going wrong. However, I am unable to get it working on Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

A related issue has been reported once [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/162#issuecomment-9017997). You have to use single quotes to avoid shell expansion. I'm not sure if that applies to Windows as well, though.

Comment: Tried this `Rscript -e '(knitr::knit2html(text = "## good\n `r 1 + 1`", fragment.only = TRUE))'` and got this.
`ARGUMENT '~+~`r~+~1~+~+~+~1`",~+~fragment.only~+~=~+~TRUE))' __ignored__`

Comment: OK. It looks like an issue of your specific shell; this works for me: Rscript -e '(knitr::knit2html(text = "## good\n `r 1 + 1`", fragment.only = TRUE))' (backticks were eaten by SO). I'm under Ubuntu, and my `$SHELL` is `bash`. I do not know what is the default shell for Mac (is there such a thing `echo $SHELL`?)

Comment: I did `echo $SHELL` and it returned `bin/bash`. I need to dig deeper what the source of error is.